# flex: Unicode symbol in rich text

Tags: apache-flex, unicode, fonts, flex4

I have richtext in which I need to display unicode symbol U+03A9 Ω​. What is the easiest way to achieve this- so far we are using built-in fonts. Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Have you got an error? Where's the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the \uXXXX syntax:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function setViaActionScript():void {
                // use \uXXXX for unicode characters
                rt.text = "Resistance: 45 \u03A9";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:RichText id="rt" text="Resistance: 90 \u03A9" click="setViaActionScript()"/>

</s:Application>
```